# How to pass variable from client to server and persist it in the server for other functions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In my google appscripts web app, I have a variable defined in the client (js) file.  Let's call that variable qty.  I need that variable in a number of server functions, so currently I'm doing this:

```
<script>
google.script.run.serverFunction(qty);
</script>
```

And my server script looks like this:

```
function serverFunction(qty) {
      ... 
      INSERT INTO table (blah) VALUES (qty);
      ...
    }
```

But instead, I want to pass qty to server once, set it as a global variable (?) ... so that I can use it directly in all my server functions and not have to pass it from the client every time.

Why do I need this? 
Because currently, a savvy user can run `google.script.run.serverFunction(qty);` in the console and INSERT random things.  Figure if the input variable is set in server, there's more control.

Comment: You will need to use `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()` and put the data into the Properties Service.  However, one property can only hold 9k of data.  If your data is over 9k, you'll need to split it up.  If it's a lot more than 9k, like 100k, then it might not work to put data into the Properties Service.  If you only need to hold the data for less than 6 hours, you can use Cache Service, and store up to 100k in one property.  [Apps Script Documentation - Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#put(String,String,Integer))

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood.  (I'm new around here so wondering why you didn't make this an answer).  

I just tried getUserProperties() and it's looking great.  I'm unsure about timing.  I'm using firebase for authentication, so I'm wondering how appscripts considers a "user", and how long the value will be stored.  But I'm feeling confident that this will definitely do the job!

Thank you!

Comment: Good question.  I *did* just add it as an answer.  There are the official rules, then what actually happens, and lot's of different opinion.  In this case I probably should have just created an answer.  When I first started to provide information, I wasn't planning on giving the detailed answer, but it turned into that.  The answer doesn't include code, and your question doesn't include much code, so I decided it was better to be in error in the comments.  Nobody can down vote my comment.  If I give an answer, and somebody thinks that it's not appropriate, they could down-vote me.

Comment: The unfortunate reality is, that answering in the comments feels "safer" to me than giving an answer that somebody might not like.  It's too bad, that this is how it ends up being, but that's how it is.  I personally don't like it when questions go unanswered, because when I'm searching for information, I look for an approved answer.  New people often ask questions that have already been answered, because if you don't know the correct terminology, the search system often doesn't return what you need.  So, to some degree, I'm just "playing the system."  If a comment becomes an answer, safe.

Comment: Well, I liked your answer and I'm going with it.  Unfortunately I can't upvote it because I don't have any reputation.  Ugh!  I'm sure smart people came up with this system, but I read stackoverflow almost daily and never really engage with it because it always seemed complicated and snooty.

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct even though you can't upvote.  Click the big green check mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use:

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
```

and put the data into the Properties Service. However, one property can only hold 9k of data. If your data is over 9k, you'll need to split it up. If it's a lot more than 9k, like 100k, then it might not work to put data into the Properties Service. If you only need to hold the data for less than 6 hours, you can use Cache Service, and store up to 100k in one property.

[Apps Script Documentation - Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#put(String,String,Integer))